# send file on cloudprint

Tags: file, post, base64, httprequest

wrote request:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length: SizeString

Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token

&printerid=2deb8a6d-86d7-4345-f3ad-ad7e0f7d2591&title=testname&ticket=testticket&content=base64string&contentTransferEncoding=base64
```

and connection to www.google.com/cloudprint/submit

But no response from server (timeout error). what am I doing wrong?
For example, No problem with connection to www.google.com/cloudprint/list:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length: SizeString

Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token

&proxy=3D9B828E-F8FD-4F83-A32F-96F1F0B35C6B
```